# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filename'

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples, attributeerror

I'm trying to import matplotib in my code, but as soon as I type

```
import matplotlib
```

in the shell, it throws a full junk of trace back and last few lines reading

```
File "path\pyparsing.py", line 793, in extract_stack
return [(frame_summary.filename, frame_summary.lineno)]

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

I use Python3.4.4 (64-bit). I've tried re-installing the module (with pip). On every install it says "Installed Successfully" and then throws the above mentioned error whenever I try to import it.

Comment: The traceback is valuable data for debugging. Might even help answering your post.

Comment: It shows error in the file pyparsing.py

Comment: Yes it is. Found my Answer. Thank You.